# Как определить когда система нуждается в перезагрузке после установки обновлений?

Tags: linux, debian

Как определить когда система нуждается в перезагрузке после установки обновлений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

исходя из личного опыта, я считаю, что есть только два однозначных повода для перезагрузки по результатам обновления пакетов:

1. вы установили новую версию программу *linux* и хотите её перезапустить.
2. вы установили новую версию стандартных си-библиотек (*[e]glibc/uclibc/dietlibc/musl/* и т.п.)

ещё бывают случаи, когда вы не уверены, что в системе установлены (и работают в данный момент) программы **только** из официального репозитория (эти-то будут перезапущены мэйнтэйнерскими скриптами при необходимости), **и** были обновлены **какие-нибудь** библиотеки. в этом случае, чем выяснять наличие таких «левых» программ и перезапускать их, проще бывает перезагрузить систему.

Comment: Неужели нет какого нибудь простого индикатора? Например файл: `/var/run/reboot-required`

Comment: Короче, установил себе needrestart - https://packages.debian.org/stretch/needrestart

Comment: @Hipster о каком типе установки идет речь? В ДЦ если перезагружать сервера, после каждого обновления - с клиентами ведь не расплачешся. Самый долгий uptime за время моей работы - 420 дней, пришлось выключить полетел винт : -), не меряйте *nix мерками Windows.

Comment: @Hellseher, 390 дней на моём основном сервере. Полёт нормальный, тьфу-тьфу-тьфу. Посмотрим скока ещё продержится

Comment: Речь идёт о небольшом веб-сервере, а при больших нагрузках конечно надо использовать связку и там уже перезагружай сколько хочешь.

Answer (score 0):

Мое мнение:

Есть только один повод перегрузить linux: ядро. Новое или добавление модулей ядра (или же внесение модулей в blacklist при работе с ними). Во всех остальных случаях достаточно рестарта программного обеспечения или же службы.

Comment: *Есть только один повод перегрузить linux: ядро* — с одной стороны, вроде, «масло масляное», а с другой стороны — нонсенс: ведь функции ядра операционной системы может выполнять не только программа linux.

Answer (score 0):

В гноме-3 на дебиане и на убунте горит красненький значек на панели.